# How to filter a queryset of Tag objects by current user

Tags: django, django-serializer

I need to filter **tags** by current user, in serializers class I can not do request  -queryset=TagPrivate.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

```
serializers.py

    class DotPrivateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        tag = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            many=False,
            queryset=TagPrivate.objects.all() # <-------------------------- filter by user
        )
    
        class Meta:
            model = DotPrivate
            fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'lat', 'lon', 'rating', 'link', 'tag')
            read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

...so is there any way to do it in views.py?

```
class DotPrivateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = serializers.DotPrivateSerializer
    queryset = DotPrivate.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """"Return objects for the current authenticated user only"""

        return self.queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually get a current use in DRF using this [class here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) . In your case if you want to filter from the serializer you can do this

```
 class DotPrivateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_private_tags = TagPrivate.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user)
    tag = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=False,
        queryset=user_private_tags # <-------------------------- filter by user
    )

    class Meta:
        model = DotPrivate
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'lat', 'lon', 'rating', 'link', 'tag')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

I belive you are likely to have more than one tag, so you might want to set `many=True`

> ...so is there any way to do it in views.py?

The answer is yes, there is away as described [here in the doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

```
class DotPrivateViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = serializers.DotPrivateSerializer
    queryset = DotPrivate.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        """"Return objects for the current authenticated user only"""
        queryset = self.queryset
        query_set = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return query_set
```

Now it is up to you what to go with now.

Comment: I had some problems with CurrentUserDefault(), is that because method filed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73524934/typeerror-field-id-expected-a-number-but-got-class-rest-framework-fields-cu/73524985#73524985

Comment: Try the answer I have given, I have seen (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73524934/typeerror-field-id-expected-a-number-but-got-class-rest-framework-fields-cu/73524985#73524985] you called the class like `serializers.CurrentUserDefault` instead of `serializers.CurrentUserDefault()`

Comment: Yes in my code there is serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), like you recommended, nevertheless y get:
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got CurrentUserDefault().

Comment: OK, I have seen the error and the solution could be to get the user from the context passed from the view itself. I have updated that, and you can override `get_serializer_context(self)` in the view to pass current user